# Десериализация ObservableCollection

Tags: c#

Есть такой класс с коллекцией:

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Sound { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Example
{
    public ObservableCollection<Animal> animals { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Animal>()
    {
        new Animal() {Sound = "Гав"},
        new Animal() {Sound = "Мяу"},
        new Animal() {Sound = "Кря"}
    };

    public Example()
    {

    }
}
```

Сериализую в XML и все проходит нормально. Файл выглядит так:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Example xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <animals>
    <Animal>
      <Sound>Гав</Sound>
    </Animal>
    <Animal>
      <Sound>Мяу</Sound>
    </Animal>
    <Animal>
      <Sound>Кря</Sound>
    </Animal>
  </animals>
</Example>
```

Но после десериализации в коллекции находятся 6 элементов, вместо 3-х.
Как я понимаю это происходит из-за того, что при создании экземпляра класса в коллекцию добавляются изначальные 3 элемента благодаря конструктору, а затем добавляются еще 3 при десериализации.

Как сделать, чтобы после десериализации в коллекции не было ничего лишнего?

Comment: А что если вынести инициализацию в конструктор по умолчанию?

Comment: @iluxa1810, Не помогает. Помогло вынести инициализацию коллекции в отдельный метод, но может быть есть какой-то еще вариант.

Comment: я думаю, что атрибуты,которые я описал в ответе должны помочь.

Comment: @iluxa1810, Спасибо, буду разбираться!

Comment: А почему таки эти данные в конструкторе класса\свойства, а не снаружи? Они же нужны только первый раз, поэтому я бы унёс этот код туда, где решается, загрузка это с диска или создание свежего экземпляра класса.

Comment: @Monk, В данном примере конечно, можно так сделать. Но в рабочем мне нужно, чтобы инициализация была именно в классе.

Comment: Прагматичное решение — убрать добавление элементов, и добавлять их после того, как конструктор отработает.

Comment: @VladD, по идее, если в конструктор по умолчанию добавить animals проверку и на наличие элементов и только если они пуста инициализировать ее начальными значениями?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Не сработает. Сериализация сначала вызывает конструктор, а потом добавляет объекты. Так что проверка в конструкторе обнаружит пустой список в любом случае.

Comment: @maxwell опиши лучше, как ты этим пользоваться собрался. Пока выглядит не очень рабоче.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Есть решение в лоб:**

1. Создать отдельный конструктор, которому на вход подается путь к XML.
   Загружаем XML в память и проходимся ручками по нему, что бы
   выполнить правильную инициализацию.
2. Сделать дополнительный именованный конструктор для пользователя и добавить логику заполнения коллекции тула.
   Этим конструктором будут создавать объект пользователи и там будет
   инициализации коллекции начальными значениями, а десериализатор
   будет использовать конструктор по умолчанию.

Может быть есть еще какие-то интересные решения, но эти самые быстрые в реализации.